Atlas - Legend changing between pages
I'm setting up an atlas in QGIS to export tens of maps as fast as possible.
One thing I don't understand is why the legend I put almost always move between the maps.


The size is dynamic as some elements appears on some maps and some don't but I did set the position to the lower right corner and the X and Y position as I want the legend to expand if needed to the top left side.


it looks like the dynamic legend 'auto-update' needs switch off, if there are more layers in the next map is it trying to accomadate them in the legend.

It's already switch off, however, the first layer is a classification with a variable number of class depending on the map.

I haven't been able to get lower-right anchoring to work either, over several versions. The dynamic size seems to override the anchoring. I usually just suck it up with a static sized legend and live with the whitespace, or have the legend placed (and anchored) to the top left.

Yes, these two options are what I'm usually doing. I guess there is no real solution here, thanks.
